# SQL - Generate counts for "mismatched" records

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark-sql, metabase

I am now trying to use Metabase v0.29 to develop a question. Suppose I have three tables and would like to produce an output table shown below.

**Table 1 - Job/Student ID (job_student_ids)**

```
Job ID   Student ID
J101     S101
J101     S102
J102     S101
```

**Table 2 - Job Items (job_items)**

```
Job ID   Job Item
J101     Apple
J101     Orange
J102     Apple
J102     Banana
```

**Table 3 - Student Items (student_items)**

```
Student ID   Student Item
S101         Apple
S101         Orange
S102         Pear
S102         Orange
S103         Apple
S103         Orange
```

**Output Table - Item Matches**

```
Job Item   Student Item Match
Apple      3
Orange     2
Banana     1
```

**Example explanation - how to work out *Apple*?**

Notice both J101 and J102 request *Apple* (shown in Table 2), and J101 has applicants S101 and S102 (shown in Table 1) while J102 only has applicant S101.

J101: One match from applicant S101 who has an *Apple*, another match from applicant S102 who also has an *Apple* (shown in Table 3). Therefore 2 *Apple* matches.

J102: One match from applicant S101 who has an *Apple*.

Hence, in total 3 matches for *Apple*.

**Please note**: Due to the actual size of Table 1-3 on our database, it is impossible to append/union all of them together to make that count.

Is there any efficient way to achieve this goal? Thanks in advance - this is my first time to post a question here so please let me know if you'd like any clarifications.

Comment: J101 referring job item both apple and orange Same way j102 referring both apple n banana. Is this correct? Is that data like this?

Comment: @Gaj Yes - that's right :)

Comment: You don't show any attempt to solve the problem.